# expand org variable value in situ

Tags: org-mode, variables, org-link

Is there a way to link to an orgmode variable's value?
Or at least export it?

I can get a link to jump to the variable definition,
but not display its value or export.

for example the text in testmesage below should read:
"and I'm like wut ever"

I'm trying to insert live data into a document without turning the whole thing in a src block and using `:var`.

```
* huh
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
echo "wut ever"
#+END_SRC
#+NAME: ww
#+RESULTS:
: wut ever

* testmessage
and I'm like [[ww]]
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: I'm looking for something like this as well.  Possibly more in the form of a constant that could be viewed in two forms 1) the value and 2) the substitution variable (like your `[[ww]]`.  I'd want to toggle between the two modes perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [inline evaluation of code blocks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html)? Name your code block with `#+name: ww` and then use `and I'm like call_foo()`. Like this:

```
* huh
#+NAME: ww
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
echo "wut ever"
#+END_SRC
#+NAME: ww
#+RESULTS:
: wut ever

* testmessage
and I'm like call_ww()
#+END_SRC
```

You can execute the inline code block by pressing `C-c C-c` on it and it will have its result appended after the call in the buffer:

```
 ... and I'm like call_foo() {{{results(=wut evah=)}}}
```

That's a `verbatim` `wut evah`: you can customize the format a bit using the variable `org-babel-inline-result-wrap`'. The built-in [Org macro](https://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-Replacement.html) `results` just returns its argument unchanged, but you can also redefine that if you want to do something different: Org mode's middle name is flexibility :-). But note that the doc cautions against that:

> Moreover, inline source blocks (see *note Structure of Code Blocks::)
> use the special ‘results’ macro to mark their output.  As such, you are
> advised against re-defining it, unless you know what you are doing.

In any case, exporting the document (I would tag the `huh` section as `:noexport:` so it does not appear in the exported output) produces what you want, I think.